# Can most optimization problems be framed and tackled as reinforcement learning problems?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, reinforcement-learning

There is a clear overlap between both. Which characteristics can help us identify problems that could be tackled as classic optimization and rf also?

Answer (score 2):

In general, if your problem can be expressed as a [Markov Decision Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process), you can apply reinforcement learning to it. This means the following flowchart should be a good visual representation, where an agent takes an action $A_t$ in some state $S_t$ and the environment responds with a reward $R_{t+1}$ and a new state $S_{t+1}$.

[image: MDP diagram]

I am definitely not saying that every problem that can be expressed as an MDP *should* be solved with reinforcement learning. If for example, you were trying to optimize some known convex function, you *could* frame it as an RL problem. But why would you when there are already incredibly efficient solvers of these problems already?

RL is often turned to for its generality. I would usually try RL only if there weren't an easier way.